# Execute Stored Procedure in PHP not working

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, view

We are currently using this PHP code in order to query a view however, we want this to now execute a stored procedure.

```
$sMSSQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM [reporting].[dbo].Report_thereport_cc;";

$aResults = RunMSSQLQuery($sMSSQLQuery);

echo json_encode($aResults);
```

When we try and run the above against a stored procedure, we get a Database Query Error. What do we need to change in order for it to work?

Comment: Can you please share the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execuse Store Procedure you must use EXEC statement like this

```
EXEC storeProcedure1
```

I'm not sure when use with php but try this

```
$sMSSQLQuery = "EXEC [reporting].[dbo].Report_thereport_cc;";

$aResults = RunMSSQLQuery($sMSSQLQuery);

echo json_encode($aResults);
```